# How to check if there is any colored cell within a specific range?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm looking for an Excel formula that checks if there is any colored cell within a row.
If there is, in the same row in column 2 (Which is actually column B) **Print** **"Yes"**, otherwise **print** **"No"**.

I tried this formula to check in the second row:

```
=IF(2:2.Interior.Color=4,"Yes","No")
```

Maybe the solution should be written in VBA code rather than Excel formula.

Here is how I want it to look:
[image: Here is how I want it to look:]

Comment: Check [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/troubleshoot/office-developer/count-cells-number-with-color-using-vba)

Comment: "not working" - What's happening instead of it working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In vba you can try with this code: In this exemple i used The range C2 TO F10, but you can change the values that are into startRow, endRow, startCol end in endCol to change the range.

```
Sub MyInteriorColor()

Const COLOR As Integer = 4 ' here you can change the color    
Dim startRow, endRow, startCol, endCol, i, c As Integer

startRow = 2 ' Read the interior color from second row
endRow = 10 ' Last row where i read the interior color

startCol = 3 ' Column where i start to read the interior color
endCol = 6 ' Column where i finish to read interior color

For i = startRow To endRow
    For c = startCol To endCol
    
        If Cells(i, c).Interior.ColorIndex = COLOR Then
            Cells(i, 2) = "YES"
            Exit For
        Else
            Cells(i, 2) = "NO"
        End If
    Next c
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. works perfectly. 

Is there any way to know how many used rows/rows with data there is?
so I can make The variable "endRow" constant and not hardcoded.

Thanks!

Comment: yes you can use this :
lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

lastColumn = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

if my answer in the post is been helpful for you, i appreciate your voteup. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think a UDF I probably a better way to do this.
That way each cell can point to whatever range it needs.
Place this code in a module:

```
Function IsGreen(rng as range)
    IsGreen = "No"

    for each cell in rng
        If cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 4 then
            IsGreen = "Yes"
            Exit for
        end if
    next cell
End function
```

And to use this you enter the formula in column 2:

```
=IsGreen(C2:G2)
```

And it should return yes/no.
I typed this answer on my phone so I have not been able to test it but I believe it will work.

Comment: I like your solution @Andreas! One question, if I have a sheet with many cells to insert the function, the file gets slower?

Comment: Don't know for sure, but I assume so since each cell will recalculate. The other solution does everything once and then nothing until you want to "manually update" by running the code. Edit: thought I was talking to OP. Yes I believe your code will outperform mine if there is lots of things changing. But yours needs to be run manually.